# How to select polygon by searching its coordinate using ArcGIS Javascript?

Tags: html, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to build a webapp using ArcGIS JS API. Got the Search widget to search within the layer attributes. But how do I make the Search widget select underlying polygon whenever I enter any coordinates? Can this be done using ArcGIS JS?

How to make Search widget select underlying polygon when coordinates is entered?

Answer (score 1):

The Search widget find features base on attributes, in your case you need base on geometry, so it will not suit you there.

Anyway, it is not hard to achieve what you want. You just need a spatial query, in particular query for any polygon that contains the inpu point. For that use layer's method `queryFeatures` ([ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#queryFeatures)). Set the query parameter with the correct spatial queries options ([ArcGIS JS API - Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-support-Query.html)).

Something like this will suit in your case,

```
let query = myPolygonLayer.createQuery(); // myPolygonLayer is the layer where you want to query
query.geometry = point;  // user input point
// distance and units if you want to buffer the point to help user
// query.distance = 5;
// query.units = "meters";
query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = [ "*" ];
myPolygonLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results){
    // returns a feature set with features
    console.log(results.features);
});
```

Here you have an esri sample doing something similar [ArcGIS JS Samples - FeatureLayer Basic Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurelayer-query-basic/)